# tensorflow - LinearRegressor - How to extract model weights

Tags: tensorflow

How would one extract the feature weights of a model trained with `tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor`?

I have tried to call `weights_` and pretty much any method the docs have provided on the trained model.

My aim to use this to convert into a decision tree.